# dual boot window 7

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, windows

I'm trying to use boot camp to dual boot windows 7 with mac. but i get this error

"An error occurred while partitioning the disk. Please run Disk Utility to check and fix the error."

I run disk utility and check for errors and everything is ok

"First Aid process is complete, click Done to continue."

I try to do manual disk partition and i get this

"Operation failed…"

"Running operation 1 of 1: Add “Untitled” by splitting “Macintosh HD”…

"Checking prerequisites for resizing Logical-Physical volume stack
The requested size change for the target disk or a related disk is too small. Please try a different disk or partition, or make a larger change.
Operation failed…"

Please any help?

Comment: Some screen shots would be helpful and also the size of your disk and the sizes you want to change the partitions to. Note that depending on how much data Boot Camp thinks Windows needs and how much space macOS is using the sizes you choose may not work and you may have to settle for sizes that are not optimal for your needs.